# Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have just been running into some issues upgrading from ruby 1.9.3-p194 to 1.9.3-p286 with RVM. I've managed to fix them all until now, when I run the bundler I get the following:

```
~/rp/tp[master*]$ bundle update

Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
/home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
    from /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:279:in `update'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/bin/bundle:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/bin/bundle:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you sure you have `libcrypto.so.0.9.8` somewhere?

Comment: Are you running `bundle update` with your newest version of ruby?

Comment: @halfelf Excuse my ignorance, how can I check that?

Comment: @Deepack Yes, ruby -v = ruby 1.9.3p286

Comment: Try search it in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure all libraries are installed properly, RVM shows the required libraries and how to install them:

```
rvm requirements
```

it is important you remove all other versions of **openssl** and leave only one matching versions of openssl + openssl-dev(el).

After this you need to reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: There was only one version of openssl, I ran `rvm pkg install openssl` and that did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Running "rvm requirements" solves the problem. Thanks @mpapis